# adding access-control-origin header using axios

Tags: javascript, post, axios, cors, liveserver

I am trying to send post data using this code

```
  axios
.post(
  data.submissionUrl,
  { data: sendData },
  { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" } }
)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err, err.response);
});
```

and I am getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website' from origin 'vscode live server' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

however I don't know for what reason if I swap data and headers places the headers are joined with data and the post goes through but the data is incorrect. `data: "{"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`

Answer (score -1):

You cant do that. You need to add that header in the server response.

Comment: so i have to add that header in the server (where I'm trying to post the data?)

Comment: yes, most server frameworks have some middlewares to do that. For example, for express: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: You can use a proxy too. It s  a common way get rid of cors. If you are serving your front app with nginx, you can setup a reverse proxy to make a redirection of '/api' to website. Your app and /api will be on the same host so the browser wont care about cors.

Answer (score -1):

- i think that you used axios on Browser because if you used it with nodejs you won't get any problems with cors i suggest you to do it from your server by nodejs and you can get the data by http request for your server what i mean is

1. create a script that sending the data from your  server by nodejs
2. create your browser script that sending a request to your server to get this data it's will be better if you using that in a website